# HTML: Why script tags should always have full ending?

Tags: html, cross-browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don’t self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

I wonder why scripts included into header html tag should always have full ending `<tag></tag>` like this:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

while xml well-formed shortened form `<tag/>` makes browsers crazy:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" />
```

Browsers tend to demonstrate blank screen instead of page, though html layout is present.

**EDIT:**

Thank you guys, my question is duplicate to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work) asked earlier

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work

Comment: remember: html is not fully xml-compatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Why don't self-closing script tags work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 1):

[W3.org - 18.2.1 The SCRIPT element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)

```
<!ELEMENT SCRIPT - - %Script;          -- script statements -->
<!ATTLIST SCRIPT
  charset     %Charset;      #IMPLIED  -- char encoding of linked resource --
  type        %ContentType;  #REQUIRED -- content type of script language --
  src         %URI;          #IMPLIED  -- URI for an external script --
  defer       (defer)        #IMPLIED  -- UA may defer execution of script --
  >
```

> Start tag: required, End tag: required